# How do I solve this mixed integer program?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming, binary-programming

I have a minimisation problem in the following form
$$\textrm{min}: x^TAx$$
constrained by $\sum x_i=N$

where $x$ is a vector containing only 1's and 0's, and $A$ is a square matrix of real numbers.

In my case size($x$) is very large and $0<<N<<\textrm{size}(x)$.

Is there a class of methods for solving this program efficiently?

Many thanks for anybody's help!

Comment: As far as Iunderstand your question, since $x$ is allowed only to have 1 and 0 as components then, given a fixed $N$ you want to find the submatrix $A_\vec{N}$ of $A$ whose elements sum $x^TAx$ is the least, where $\vec N = (i_1,\dots, i_N)$ a tuple of components for which $x$ has 1 only. ($1 \le i_1 < \dots < i_N \le \dim V, x\in V$)

Comment: @Physor Thank you for your response. I think that is a correct interpretation of the problem! Although I later also want to consider the constraint $\sum x_i < N$, but for now the current problem is OK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to convert this into a integer linear program and what is the best way to solve such a problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519527/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-this-into-a-integer-linear-program-and-what-is-t)

Comment: @RobPratt As far as I understand I have a quadratic program, whilst the one you posted is linear.

Comment: Indeed, they are different.  The notation and wording are so similar that I mistook this question as a duplicate.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3722722/683666

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the dimension of $x.$ For any $i,j\in \lbrace 1,\dots,M\rbrace$ with $i\neq j,$ the term $A_{i,j}$ appears in the objective value if and only if $A_{j,i}$ also appears (i.e., if and only if $x_i=1=x_j$). So we can do a bit of preprocessing by replacing $A_{i,j}$ and $A_{j,i}$ with their average $(A_{i,j}+A_{j,i})/2.$ After this step, we have an equivalent problem with a symmetric $A$ matrix. Also, if it proves useful (I'm not sure it will), we can exploit the fact that we know the number of $A_{i,j}$ that will end up in the objective sum ($N^2$), so if we want $A\ge 0$ we can just subtract the smallest entry in $A$ from every entry in the matrix, which produces an equivalent problem (where the objective value is changed by a constant amount).

Armed with that, consider a complete graph with $M$ nodes, where each edge $(i,j)$ has weight $A_{i,j}.$ Your problem can now be stated as selecting a minimum weight $N$-clique from the graph. If you search for "minimum weight clique", you will find relevant references. Here is one: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2221/heuristics-for-the-minimum-weight-k-clique-problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply - I will look into this. I am curious to know how you think your approach would compare (in terms of speed and scalability for large x) to a linearisation of the problem (as suggested here: math.stackexchange.com/a/3722722/683666 ) solved with a MILP solver?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea, since I have not paid attention to research on the weighted $k$-clique problem.